# Windows 10 network stack is truncating TCP packets

Tags: windows-10

I am seeing a weird issue that I am not sure how to debug further.

I am on Windows 10, version 1511 (OS Build 10586.318)

I am working w/ an internal web service that returns json and noticed today that it started to return malformed json (The last '}' is missing) when I hit the endpoint directly from installed web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge). This does not happen when I invoke the endpoint from Powershell or C#.

I have installed Wireshark locally and on the application server hosting the web service. A quick capture in both locations shows that the packet is getting sent correctly and received correctly (with the last '}' intact).

However, when I capture traffic with Fidder4 the last '}' is missing.

To add to the fun, this issue does not occur for anyone on Windows 7 or Ubuntu LTS hitting the same service.

Any ideas on how to debug this further?

Update 1:
I took another look at the packet captured by Wireshark, the packet captured by Fiddler4, and the response as seen by Chrome in dev tools. I noticed that the "Content-Encoding: deflate\r\n" header is missing. I don't know why it is going missing.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but does the output of your service end with a CRLF?

Comment: @Flup The last character returned is the bracket

Comment: I wonder if this is something trying to be a bit too clever, and stripping the last character assuming it will be a newline.  Just a guess, but I've seen similar things before.

Comment: @Flup I looked @ the packets again - it looks like somewhere Windows is losing the "Content-Encoding: deflate\r\n" header. It is present in the packet capture from Wireshark, but missing in the capture from Fiddler and the developer console in chrome.

Comment: Fiddler is a proxy and it is changing a bit the traffic. I had once some problems that were 'solved' just by using Fiddler. I do not recall the details. It is very good, but you shouldn't trust it blindly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not expect to have a network issue, because the captures with Wireshark have the '}'.

I suspect a bug in the antivirus or in a browser plugin.

Notes from poster:
This ended up being a bug w/ ESET's Endpoint Antivirus suite - specifically a feature called "ESET Web access protection". For now, re-configuring this feature to exclude internal traffic has solved the issue.